# How to create multi line string with a scroll bar in Progress 4gl?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

There is a "Comments" field in my database. I would like to display the content of this field in Progress 4gl in a Windows environment. The item should have a scroll bar to allow being viewed with the full text (in the "Comments" field) throughout the progress.
How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give a lot of info, so I'll call the field comments. You said windows environment, but is that GUI or CHUI? If GUI, just use an editor widget to display it. If it's CHUI, something along the lines of

```
DISPLAY comments view-as editor size 30 /* columns */ by 5. /* Lines */
```